# ReactJS align material-ui elements horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to have a radio button next to a text input so essentially a user can input "answers" to a question and mark one preferred. However, Material-UI puts each on it's own line.

This is what I currently have :

```
<div>
   <RadioButton
      value="light"
   />
   <TextInput
       hintText="Answer"
       multiLine = {true}
   />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the record, I managed to align radio buttons using [flexboxgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/)... Did something like this:

```
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-2">
          Type:
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-10">
          <RadioButtonGroup
             className="row"
             name="type">
            <RadioButton
               className="col-md-4"
               value="other"
               label="Other" />
            <RadioButton
               className="col-md-4"
               value="custom"
               label="Custom" />
          </RadioButtonGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using [react-inline-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inline-grid) for layout with material-ui, it helps solve many problems and makes code more explicit about layout (plus it's reactive).

```
<Grid>
  <Row is="nospace start">
    <Cell is="9 tablet-6 phone-3">
       <TextField ... />
    </Cell>
    <Cell is="middle 3 tablet-2 phone-1">
       <RaisedButton ... />
    </Cell>
  </Row>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Awesome find. This functionality needs to be in Material-UI proper. Horizontal layouts are hard in Material-UI now.

Comment: Does the `is` parameter work out of the box or do you need to have Bootstrap installed?

Comment: Based upon your answer here, I found [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) which looks similar but is more explicit in the breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will check these 2 options out!

Comment: @LarryMaccherone there's no need for bootstrap at all... it's material-ui only... `is` is just the parameter for {Grid, Row, Cell} from `react-inline-grid`

Comment: @ChrisHartwig do you really have to wrap your entire app in `<Grid>` ? I'm having some trouble implementing it

Comment: @erichardson30 I wrap in a Grid when I need it... It can be nested (AFAIK I'm using nested grids).
ie. most of the time, the Grid is local to a component...

Answer (score 2):

You have a `style`  object available to override the default styles of the element in Material-Ui.
Use that and set display to inline-block.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: @erichardson30 does it solves your issue or you needed something else?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but I will today and will let you know

Comment: I added in style={{display: 'inline-block'}} to each of the elements and that didn't make a difference

Comment: @WitVault It worked for me, but wasn't very flexible. Ultimately I ended up going with `react-inline-grid`. Took about 2 minutes.

Comment: @Trenton i just tried `react-inline-grid`, but i got error tht said something with react-redux, it seems requiring react-redux  :/