# How to stack elements (cards) horizontally in a row within a parent element (div)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a question very similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995511/reactjs-align-material-ui-elements-horizontally/42725686).

I have forked the Material UI Card example from https://material-ui.com/demos/cards/. The link [to the sandbox editor is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9j18zzn25y).

Basically I need to stack Material UI cards horizontally in one row within a parent div and when they do not fit they would create another row bellow the previous.

So when i write:

```
render(
    <div className="row">
      <Demo /> <Demo />
    </div>,
    rootElement
  );
```

I expect to get the two cards besides one another.

I have added following styles with `display: "inline-block"`, but the cards still stack vertically:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    minWidth: 275,
    display: "inline-block"
  }
};
```

Comment: Because you should use that custom style on `div` element that is parent of card https://codesandbox.io/s/82xn3oppr8, but maybe better solution is to use `Grid` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of changes needed

1) Firstly the parent div needs to be inline-block as well. This is to ensure div can be aligned side by side

2) set white-space to nowrap to ensure elements do not wrap to the next line. Just because divs are inline-block does not mean they would be aligned side by side. If the inline div exceeds the width, it will be wrapped to the next line. You need to stop it by setting white-space param

https://codesandbox.io/s/9y51rxjmxy

Comment: Thanks, but I still see them aligned vertically in the demo?

Comment: can you reload the link i pasted above? Its working for me

Comment: So I need to wrap the card in another div?

Comment: Your card is already wrapped in a div which was not inline-block. I did not add any new element. You can remove inline-block from the card itself

Answer (score 0):

How about adding:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    minWidth: 275,
    float: "left",
    marginRight: 10 // or sth.
  }
};
```

The problem is, that the  wraps its content in a div which by default is display: block; - thats why display: inline-block doesn't work here on the Demo component.